# secure user email in Meteor

Tags: security, collections, meteor

I have a list of users. I don't want to publish all user data to the client, especially emails. I have multiple publish methods where i can use:

```
Meteor.publish('usersData', function() {
    return Users.find({}, {
        fields: {
            emails: 0
        }
    });
});
```

But what if I or other programmer forget to filter fields and just publish whole collection:

```
Meteor.publish('users', function() {
    return Users.find();
});
```

It's a problem. There should be global settings to filter data in collection. Is there any way how to do it in current (0.6.6.3) Meteor?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method you use instead of the normal `collection.find` method that you use anywhere you need to publish users. An example could be:

```
function findUsers(query) {
    return Meteor.users.find(query || {}, { fields: { emails: 0 } });
}
```

And then you can just remind your programmers to use the `findUsers` method:

```
Meteor.publish('userData', function () {
    return findUsers({ points: { $gt: 5 } });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I have done something like this, but I forgot to use it! I published user data with emails accidentally just because I forgot to use my function...  I need Users.find() to return data without certain fields all the time by default - globally. And there should be ability to turn it off when I need user emails.

Comment: @TomášHromník well, don't forget to use it! It shouldn't be very difficult, really. If you need to be able to turn it off, just go through your code, search for "users.find", and make sure you're filtering out the emails....

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a collection observer that throws an exception whenever a user with email fields present was published.

The observer runs independently for each connected user and triggers every time a user object has been pushed to the user collection. If it is not the current user, throw an error if the object contains the email field.

Your team should then notice these exceptions during development.

```js
Meteor.publish("userCheck", function () {
  var self = this;

  var handle = Meteor.users.find({}).observeChanges({
    added: function(id) {
      var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: id});
      if (user.emails && self.userId !== id) {
        throw new Meteor.Error(500, "Must not publish other people's email!");
      }
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```